# How can I retrieve stack overflow account email id?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, google, google-openid

I have a stack overflow account with a Google account synced with it.Recently I have forgotten my Google account ID and I cannot log in to stack overflow. I have seen my account info from another persons stack overflow account.I know my Stack overflow Username , Is there any way to retrieve my Google account ID

Comment: aiemt.com get admission

Comment: very funny...!!!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you'll have to [contact the Stack Exchange team](https://stackoverflow.com/contact). If you make sure to link to the other account, and if you can include as much information to verify your identity as possible, they'll be able to merge your current account with it, thereby alleviating the problem.

There's no way to see your email from that account without being logged in, for privacy reasons. They'll work some internal magic to verify your identity against that other account.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help , you got my problem.If I can get my Google account mail ID then , the problem solved , rest I can manage within Google.

Comment: I have contacted the Stack Exchange team , waiting for their response.

Comment: @user2637403 Yeah, I understand. As far as I know, there's no way to do that. Again, that's for privacy reasons. But awesome, I'm sure they'll get that worked out as soon as possible.

Comment: hmm I hope so . Anyways thanks dude :)